# Extraindo valores de array e tranformando em inteiros

Tags: php, array

Por favor quem puder me ajudar. A questão é a seguinte, preciso extrair duas variáveis de uma array e usá-las como tipo inteiro para comparar valores entre elas. O código é esse:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM 
inf_user
WHERE
login = '" . $login
."' and senha = '" . $senha ."'";

try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Nao foi possivel executar o comando.');
    $rows = $result->fetch();

    extract($rows);

    //echo "\$limite = $limite; \$consultas = $consultas";

    $limite = intval($limite);
    $consultas = intval($consultas);

    var_dump($limite);
```

O retorno do `var_dump` é `int(2)`, mas eu preciso que seja somente o número `2` sem o `int()`. Como faço?

Comment: Sua string tem um padrão? isso aí parece a declaração de um campo (SQL). Lembre que o `var_dump()` adiciona uma formatação na saída. Verifique a saída com `echo` também.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo acessar a valor de retorno acessando os índices dos arrays, por exemplo:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Nao foi possivel executar o comando.');
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$id = $rows['id'];
$nome = $rows['nome'];
```